# Security manager java stop override

Tags: java, securitymanager

If I set a security manager, for example:

```
private static class SecManager extends SecurityManager {
...
}
```

With:

```
System.setSecurityManager(new SecManager());
```

Which permission can I use (or rather prevent), to stop code further down the line setting the security manager again, with elevated permissions.

I am looking for a method like:

```
private static class SecManager extends SecurityManager {
    @Override
    public void checkSetSecurityManager(SecurityManager manager){
        throw new AccessControlException("Not allowed to set new security Manager);
    }
 }
```

But of course, the checkSetSecurityManager doesn't exist, so i'm not sure exactly what to look for or how to deny that permission.

I would like to use the security manager to allow me to run some untrusted code, but I obviously don't want that code to be able to set it's own security manager. I did consider doing this at the OS level (create a new user for each bit of code), but that seems a little overkill. Instead, I run my own java main, which sets a security manager, then runs the untrusted code within the same JVM. I have made sure their code cannot start new processes already (as this would circumvent the security manager), but I need to make sure they cannot override the existing security manager.

I also use checkWrite and checkRead to make sure the code can only read/write in a certain dir.

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following website https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/jg/20.+Create+a+secure+sandbox+using+a+security+manager says the following about this:

> If the current security policy enforced by the current security
>   manager forbids replacements (by omitting the
>   `RuntimePermission("setSecurityManager"))`, any attempt to invoke
>   `setSecurityManager()` will throw a SecurityException.

So it looks like the `checkPermission()` method is the place to check for this.

The Javadoc for `RuntimePermission` has a list of possible values to check for if other critical methods should be catched as well: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/RuntimePermission.html

Comment: I think this is it, so I now check permission.getAction isn't "setSecurityManager", I will do some testing but this link (and your help) seem to have pointed me in the right direction. Thanks!